# Angular Nativescript how to fix error on ng g c?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Moments earlier I created project with angular - nativescript. I've used only commands from documentation, after installing I am trying to run this command :

```
ng generate component home
```

I get this error :

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
>   '@schematics/angular/utility/parse-name' See
>   "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-JFv0M5\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.

Further details :

> [error] Error: Cannot find module
>   '@schematics/angular/utility/parse-name'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@nativescript\schematics\src\generate\component\index.js:6:22)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)

How do I fix this ?

My info :

```
√ Component nativescript has 6.0.3 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-core-modules has 6.0.7 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-android has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-ios has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.

Angular CLI: 8.3.0
Node: 10.15.3
Angular: 8.2.3
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.0
@ngtools/webpack             8.2.2
@schematics/angular          8.3.0
@schematics/update           0.803.0 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.5.2
typescript                   3.5.3
webpack                      4.27.1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had similar problem with `ng g` with Nativescript, so maybe it will help somebody

Possible errors:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@nativescript/schematics" from
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/third_party/github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/lib/typescript'
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'tslint'
```

For `tns --version`: `6.3.3`

Following dependencies are missing: `@nativescript/schematics` `@schematics/angular` `tslint`

To make it working, run:

```
npm i -D @nativescript/schematics @schematics/angular tslint
```

Comment: After these codes I got `Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
npm i -D @nativescript/schematics

npm i -D @angular/cli

ng g c test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

then,

npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

`npm install -g @schematics/angular`

and that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by executing the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
yarn global add @angular/cli
```

For any further help follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9354) as this seems to be a replica of same issue.

Comment: I have it. I installed it before , when I saw this error. Then error changed from 

Could not resolve  schematics/angular to this what I wrote in my question.

Comment: I can even find that parse-name module in my node_modules

Comment: add a period in front and give it a try. I've updated it

Comment: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @.schematics/angular@latest

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing in the project the angular CLI

```
npm install -D @angular/cli
```

and then running the command using npx

```
npx ng generate component home
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- install latest version of angular cli using:

  ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli"
  ```
- delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from your project
- run:

  ```
  npm install
  ```